# How can i get panel name by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a panel name by javascript which is expand.I am showing a list of panel dynamically by @item.Name.When i expand any of them i tried to get that expanded panel name by ... var panelId = $("#collapse").attr("name");
But i got only 1st name of panel.

Firstly i'd say i want to file send by ajax to controller with a parameter of a panel name of an expand panel.Now i want to get panel name into sumit function and then pass to controller.

index

```
 <div class="panel panel-info class" style="height: 450px; width: 300px; overflow-y:scroll;">
       @foreach (var item in lstCategory)
       {
            <div class="panel-heading" id="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" onclick="collapse(@item.Id);" name="@item.Name"  id="collapse" href="#@item.Id">@item.Name</a>                     
                </h4>
            </div>

       <div id="@item.Id" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
           <div id="file_@item.Id">
           </div>
        </div>

       }      
</div>
<form id="form" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            @*<label class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                Browse &hellip; <input type="file" name="file" class="filestyle" id="file" style="display: none;" />
            </label>*@
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file" id="browse"style="width:100%;">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="filestyle" id="file"  />
             @*<input type="file">*@
            </span>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn" id="Submit" value="Submit" style="width:100%;margin-top:5px;" disabled>
        </form>
```

javascript

```
  var panelId = $("#collapse").attr("name");
        alert("Panel name :" + panelId);


   $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#Submit').click(function (event) {


        var file = $("file").data();
        var panelId = $("#collapse").attr("name");
        alert("Panel name :" + panelId);
        var formData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("file").files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            var file = document.getElementById("file").files[i];

            formData.append("file", file);
        }
        alert(file);
            $.ajax(
       {
           url: '@Url.Action("Upload","Document")',
           type: "POST",
           data: { file: formData, Id: panelId },//{ file: formData, value: dam },//formData,
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           success: function (response) {
                 console.log(response);
           },
           error: function (error) {
               console.log(error);
           },

       });
    })
});
```

Comment: You can't have duplicated IDs (`collapse`) on your page.

Comment: Please explain what language this is? `@foreach (var item in lstCategory)`  I don't believe it's javascript or html.

Comment: Use can use $(this) to get name of active tag

Comment: @BobRodes I think asp.net !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Yeah, I think so too, but I'd like the OP to confirm it before I try to answer the question.

Comment: @BobRodes, i'm retreiving data by asp.net

Comment: LOL nice if you would say so ahead of time.  Ok, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry i did not mention clearly of my problem.My apology please.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want the name of the panel?

You can manipulate by using ***this*** with parameter of your collapse function, like:

```
onclick="collapse(this);"
```

So, you can access the parent div.

I am sorry, but your question was not very clear for me, because I do not understand what you need to do.

If you can explain a little more, It will be a pleasure to help you.

**UPDATE**

So, try to use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //I am moving your click to JQuery
    $("#collapse").click(function(){

        //Clear last selected item
        $("#collapse").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("data-selected", "");
         });

        //Mark the actual as selected
        $(this).attr("data-selected", "yes");
    });

    //Now, update your actual submit to get the actual selected item
    $('#Submit').click(function (event) {
       var nameSelected = $("#collapse[data-selected=yes]").eq(0).attr("name");

       //rest of your code here...
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm sorry i did not mention clearly of my problem.My apology please

Comment: Don't worry, please I would like to help you. It will be nice if you explain a little more what do you want, best regards.

Comment: I have a panel list that already catagorized by name and i have a submit button which is using to file upload.Now i want to pass a file and a panel name for upload the file that catagory based which i expand/select of panel.Like if i click number 3 panel and  send a file.That file will save in panel 3 catagory.I think i would understand you.

Comment: Now we are talking, lol. I will update my answer. Only few minutes please.

Comment: I have updated my answer. So, if it still not working, add me in skype: luis.pestanajr and we can solve this in live.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **$(this)** to get name of active tag. OR you can **pass name in function instead of id** : onclick="collapse(@item.name);"

```
function collapse()
{
    var itemName=$(this).attr("name")
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `$(this)` wouldn't refer to, say, the `document` object, since the OP hasn't provided any context?

Comment: And you know that the code he has posted is in the onclick event handler, or are you just assuming that?  I can't tell, personally.

Comment: here is the OP code : <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" onclick="collapse(@item.Id);" name="@item.Name"  id="collapse" href="#@item.Id">@item.Name</a>                     
                </h4>

Comment: Ok, that's better.  So, what about that `@item.id` that he's passing to the `collapse` function?  :)

Comment: OP passign id and wants name, by id he don't get anything

Comment: Yes, true.  And he hasn't explained himself very well at all.  But he says "tried to get that expanded panel name..." You're giving him the name of the  link element that is clicked, not the name of the panel he appears to be looking for.  I'm thinking we need to ask him to clarify his question before answering it, but I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: I'm sorry i did not mention clearly of my problem.My apology please